# Run several methods concurrently but in order

Tags: java, multithreading

Given 3 methods `method1()`, `method2()`, and `method3()` what would be the easiest way to run them all at the same time? (Example code would be much appreciated)

```
private void method1(){
    for(int x=0; x <= 5; x++){
        System.out.println("method 1: " + x);
    }
}

private void method2(){
    for(int x=0; x <= 5; x++){
        System.out.println("method 2: " + x);
    }
}

private void method3(){
    for(int x=0; x <= 5; x++){
        System.out.println("method 3: " + x);
    }
}
```

I would like to run them concurrently, but the output should be as follows:

```
method 1: 1
method 2: 1
method 3: 1
method 1: 2
method 2: 2
method 3: 2
method 1: 3
method 2: 3
method 3: 3
method 1: 4
method 2: 4
method 3: 4
method 1: 5
method 2: 5
method 3: 5
```

I do understand the idea of multithreading however I am unsure of how to implement it in the above way.

Comment: Look into multithreading.

Comment: Look ON http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html

Comment: Man, people are mean here. I think SO needs to be a little nicer to people who don't even know what options they have available to them. 3 downvotes and 'put on hold' is not a nice way to treat people who are just learning how to write software. Maybe I'm too nice..

Comment: You may remove the 'on hold' status. I think is no longer off-topic.

Answer (score 2):

Use something like this

```
new Thread(new Runnable() { public void run() { method1()} }).start();
```

three times.

Note, however, that this will not necessarily make them run in parallel as there is no guarantee as to when the different threads actually get to run.

If you want to get started programming concurrently in java, I can recommend this book: http://jcip.net.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/

Edit: the following is a complete example using the [CyclicBarrier](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html), which somewhat does what you expect. However, there is still no guarantee, as to in which order the individual threads are run. The only thing that is guaranteed is that the numbers are printed in order.

You are basically telling the CyclicBarrier how many parties (i.e. threads) are involved and then each one runs to the await method. The await method blocks the thread until the previously specified amount of threads are in this blocking state. Only then, the method returns (i.e. next iteration in for loop).

```
public class SyncAccessTest {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int parties = 3;
        int nprints = 3;
        CyclicBarrier barrier = new CyclicBarrier(parties);
        for (int i = 0; i < parties; i++) {
            new Thread(new Counter(barrier, nprints)).start();
        }
    }

    private static class Counter implements Runnable {

        private final CyclicBarrier barrier;

        private final int max;

        public Counter(CyclicBarrier barrier, int max) {
            this.barrier = barrier;
            this.max = max;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 1; i <= max; i++) {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getId() + ": " + i);
                try {
                    barrier.await();
                } catch (InterruptedException  ie ) {
                    return;
                } catch (BrokenBarrierException bbe) {
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```